Type Hint Compatibility Issue in Laravel When Extending Controller and Passing Specific Request Classes
I've one problem with Laravel. I want to override the parent controller's method with the child controller's method like store and update but I'm unable to handle StoreUserRequet and UpdateUserRequest in the child Controller.
CrudController.php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\BaseController;

class CrudController extends BaseController
{
    protected $service;
    protected $resource;

    public function __construct($service, $resource)
    {
        $this->service = $service;
        $this->resource = $resource;
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $this->service->create($request->validated());
        return new $this->resource($data);
    }

    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $data = $this->service->update($id, $request->validated());
        return new $this->resource($data);
    }
}

UserController.php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests\StoreUserRequest;
use App\Http\Requests\UpdateUserRequest;
use App\Services\UserService;
use App\Http\Resources\UserResource;

class UserController extends CrudController
{
    public function __construct(UserService $service)
    {
        parent::__construct($service, UserResource::class);
    }

    public function store(StoreUserRequest $request)
    {
        return parent::store($request);
    }

    public function update(UpdateUserRequest $request, $id)
    {
        return parent::update($request, $id);
    }
}

When I visit the URL http://win.test I face the below error.


Don't post images of code/data/errors. Edt your question, copy-paste the text of your error.

Can you provide code for both of these request class StoreUserRequest & UpdateUserRequest?

What you are trying to do goes against the Liskov substitution principle because it prevents UserController to be used wherever a CrudController is required even though the user controller is a child of the crud controller. This is pretty a fundamental principle of OOP and required in PHP
